# Best way to eliminate inheritance "magic" in C# winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, design-patterns, inheritance

I'm working on a legacy application wich has some flaws due to inheritance, but I'm struggling to solve it properly.

At the moment the structure of the WinForms looks like this:

- `BaseForm`
- `ListViewForm : BaseForm`
- `ListViewFormReadOnly : ListViewForm`
- `ListViewFormWithDetailForm : ListViewForm`
- `DetailForm : BaseForm`
- `ConcreteForm : ListViewFormWithDetailForm`

There is a method inside the BaseForm which is called sth like `protected virtual void InitializeMyStuff()` which is overwritten in the inherited instances.

e.g.

```
public class BaseForm {
    public BaseForm() {
       //.. do stuff

       //.. do other stuff like initialize DB connection or read app.config values and initialize properties..
}

public virtual void InitializeMyStuff() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ListViewForm : BaseForm {
    protected BindingSource GridBindingSource { get; set; }

    public ListViewForm {
       //do special stuff like adding the grid and some buttons
    }
}
public class ConcreteForm : ListViewForm {
public override void InitializeMyStuff() {
        GridBindingSource = my_bindingSource;
        SomeOtherUsefulProperty = myValue;
        Foo = new Bar();
        // etc.
    }
}

//Usage:
var myForm = new ConcreteForm();
myForm.InitializeMyStuff();
```

As you can imagine this creates some problems like:
- "What things do I have to set at this point for the form to work"
- "What things may not be initialized yet?"
- "Which properties and method calls are at my disposal yet"
and some other interesting thoughts about what may be going on in that magic blackbox.

How can I refactor this so that it gets more clear what is happening? Remember that this is a project with about 150 or more concrete forms.

My initial thought was to encapsulate those magic properties like the `GridBindingSource` for example into an object (e.g. `FormConfiguration`) and make it private in the `BaseForm`.

e.g. something like that

```
public class BaseForm {
    private FormConfigObject _formConfig = new FormConfigObject();

    protected override void OnLoad()
    {
        InitializeMyStuff(_formConfig);
    }

    protected virtual void InitializeMyStuff(FormConfigObject config)
    {}
}
```

The problem I have here is: the FormConfig object of the ListForm would have to have other properties for example, like `GridBindingSource` but I can't just change the signature in the derived classes to an `ListFormConfigObject` isntead of the `FormConfigObject`..

Can anybody suggest possible solutions to get out of this dilemma?

// Edit: straightnened out the code to what actually happens and getting rid of the virtual call in the constructor violation.

Comment: This also violates the `CA2214` rule: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx - virtual methods should not be called in the constructor.

Comment: Have you any good reason to change that? At first my idea is remove at all the `InitializeMyStuff`, a virtual call in ctor is bad idea, but this is a lot o work.

Comment: This question might be more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, the virtual call is actually hidden inside a hierachy of other methods and the real application is a lot more complex. Sorry for that mistake on my example code :/

Comment: Is BaseForm actually of type Form (or Control)? If so, you could perhaps move the call to `InitialiseMyStuff()` to an implementation of `OnCreateControl()`, which avoids the issue with calling the virtual method in a constructor, and it also means you can be sure that all the contained controls have been created by that point.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect what is really happening. Sorry for making the mistake on creation as it actually doesn't violate CA2214 but imho is a lot worse than that in reality as you basically have to initialize the object from outside..

Comment: Also, a `virtual` method which throws `NotImplementedException` usually means that it should be `abstract` rather than `virtual`.

Comment: yeah, but abstract classes in WinForms are unfortunately not possible due to designer limitations

Answer (score 3):

The main question is this: are there any objects inside `BaseForm` that:

- are required to be initialized in `BaseForm`'s constructor
- depend on the concrete implementation of the subclasses

If such objects exist then probably they should be made polymorphic, and passed into `BaseForm`'s constructor from subclasses.

A simple example, on of many possible scenarios:

```
abstract class RandomPicture
{
    public RandomPicture()
    {
        shapes = new List<Shape>();
        InitializeRandomShapes();

        // do some initial drawing calculations
    }

    protected abstract void InitializeRandomShapes();

    protected List<Shape> shapes;
}

//... subclasses initialize the shapes
```

This can be changed to:

```
abstract class RandomPicture
{
    public RandomPicture(AbstractShapeCollection shapeCollection)
    {
        shapes = shapeCollection;

        // do some initial drawing calculations
    }

    private AbstractShapeCollection shapes;
}
```

And now subclasses provide the required information through the abstract object, so the base class can proceed with it's task.

Splitting information into various objects like this is a good refactoring start, as you create more smaller objects, that are easier to test and manage and reveal the underlying structure of a mess that you've encountered. It helps also to reduce the number of violations of [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: I edited my question to sort out some mistakes made by writing up the example. There actually is no virtual call in the constructor as the initialization is called from the outside.... :/

Comment: @bberger I've removed the information about the rule from answer. But I think it pretty much stays the same - refactor into smaller objects. `OnLoad` is something like a constructor, so the in principle I'd suggest the same scenario.

Comment: yeah, this is what I would do when I can start from scratch - but this would be too much of a refactoring noone in the company would approve of :/ I need another solution for this :/

Comment: @bberger Complete refactoring from scratch is almost never recommended. Extract one object at time while doing new functionalities. Fix the code locally, when you need to modify it for a business reason. Rewriting everything that works without any other purpose than rewriting it to "look better" is pointless.

Comment: Completely agree on that. But refactoring the code to what you suggested would be almost a complete refactoring of the whole project as there are way too much dependencies which result in "magic" going on. Refactoring that part I posted in a easier maintanable solution without completely destroying the "architecture" would be my goal #1 as at least some parts of the app would get more clear and devided into smaller pieces that I can tackle when neccesary..

Comment: @bberger Well, when I look at this now, your configuration object is like going this way. The next step would be to add it as a constructor parameter, but not removing the old one. So some parts of your code can be left alone, and other parts and new ones can go with the new way. Leaving always two possible lines of execution - old and new always solves the problem of destroying the current architecture for me.